# what is exactly function in php used for

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this written in code in php test but i am not able to find where that function

`exactly` is defined . whether its php function or phpunit function.

Neither i can do google search because of very common word

`$this->exactly($count)`

Comment: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html

Comment: `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Matcher_InvokedCount exactly(int $count)`

Answer (score 0):

It's used there as a *method* (read: function defined for a class), not a procedural function. The question, then, becomes: What class does this code you mention belong to, and where is it defined? That's where you'll find the definition for your function. - Also keep inheritance in mind. Classes can inherit methods from parent classes.